# Open ListView with foreignkey from anotherlist view using a slug in django

Tags: django, listview, slug

I was able to do basically what this article - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74538383/open-listview-with-foreignkey-from-another-listview-with-django/74539496#74539496) -
says, and in the comments the person says that it would be beneficial to use a slug. How would I go about implementing the above article but with a slug. I understand how slug:pk works, I'm just not sure how to link that to a foreign key and have it filter by that pk, and then how to have it passed into the url as well.

I don't really know where to start trying to figure this out, so any help at all is appreciated, Thanks(:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.